# In Gradle, how to access the version of a dependency from the version catalog so it can be passed to a task configuration?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

(This is quite long, so scroll to the bottom for a shorter summary.)

I've run into some weird behavior with Gradle version catalogs. I'm not sure if
I'm doing things the right way, but I'm also pretty sure that I found a bug in
Gradle and/or IntelliJ.

Our Gradle build currently uses `gradle.properties` to store all of the version
information for all of our dependencies. We've been doing this since before
version catalog existed. I am now migrating our build to use version catalogs
instead. Most of this migration was fairly painless.

The one tricky part of this migration has to do with [gradle-jooq-plugin](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin). We need to pass it the version
of the jOOQ library that we’re using as a parameter, so that it will use the
matching version of the jOOQ code generator. With the properties file, this was
pretty straightforward (though somewhat verbose):

```kotlin
# All gradle build snippets are using Kotlin DSL
jooq {
    version = project.property("jooq_version") as String
```

I wasn't able to find any documentation on how to do the equivalent with
version catalogs. However, with help from IntelliJ's autocomplete, I found this,
which seems to do the right thing:

```kotlin
jooq {
    version = libs.versions.jooq.version
```

In our `gradle.properties` file we had a `_version` suffix on all of our
versions:

```
jooq_version = 3.19.4
```

At first, I used the same names in our version catalog:

```ini
[versions]
jooq_version = "3.19.4"
...
[libraries]
jooq = { module = "org.jooq:jooq", version.ref = "jooq_version" }
```

However, after I got everything working, I realized that this suffix isn't
really needed, as the versions are in their own namespace. Looking at example
version catalogs confirmed that the convention seems to be to name the versions
after what they are the version of, without anything in the name saying it's a
version.

Here's where things start to get kind of weird. I tried removing the `_version`
suffixes...

```ini
...
jooq = "3.19.4"
...
jooq = { module = "org.jooq:jooq", version.ref = "jooq" }
...
```

...and everything seemed to work **except for passing the jooq version to the
plugin**. Gradle fails with:

```
Script compilation errors:

  Line 68:     version = libs.versions.jooq.version
                                            ^ Function invocation 'version(...)' expected

  Line 68:     version = libs.versions.jooq.version
                                            ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
                                                public infix fun PluginDependencySpec.version(version: String?): PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                                                public infix fun PluginDependencySpec.version(version: Provider<String>): PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
```

Strangely, IntelliJ does **not** highlight any issues on that line.

I tried removing the `.version` suffix, to mirror the removeal of the
`_version` suffix in the toml file...

```kotlin
jooq {
    version = libs.versions.jooq
```

...but then IntelliJ highlights the line as an error, and Gradle still
complains, but with a different error:

```
  Line 68:     version = libs.versions.jooq
               ^ Val cannot be reassigned

  Line 68:     version = libs.versions.jooq
                       ^ No applicable 'assign' function found for '=' overload

  Line 68:     version = libs.versions.jooq
                         ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is LibrariesForLibs.JooqVersionAccessors! but Property<String!>! was expected
```

In IntelliJ, if I navigate to `libs.versions.jooq` and from there navigate to
its return type, JooqVersionAccessors, I see:

```java
    public static class JooqVersionAccessors extends VersionFactory  {
        private final JooqGradleVersionAccessors vaccForJooqGradleVersionAccessors = new JooqGradleVersionAccessors(providers, config);
        public JooqVersionAccessors(ProviderFactory providers, DefaultVersionCatalog config) { super(providers, config); }

            /**
             * Returns the version associated to this alias: jooq.version (3.19.4)
             * If the version is a rich version and that its not expressible as a
             * single version string, then an empty string is returned.
             * This version was declared in catalog libs.versions.toml
             */
            public Provider<String> getVersion() { return getVersion("jooq.version"); }

        /**
         * Returns the group of versions at versions.jooq.gradle
         */
        public JooqGradleVersionAccessors getGradle() {
            return vaccForJooqGradleVersionAccessors;
        }

    }
```

So there **is** a public `getVersion()` there, at least according to IntelliJ, but
Gradle isn't seeing it. I also tried method syntax just to be sure...

```kotlin
jooq {
    version = libs.versions.jooq.getVersion()
```

Again, IntelliJ is happy with this, Gradle is not:

```
Cannot access 'getVersion': it is protected in 'JooqVersionAccessors'
```

Since it seems like somehow IntelliJ and Gradle have different ideas about what
the type of `libs.versions.jooq` looks like, to get better insight about what's
going on I tried using reflection to print the methods on `libs.versions.jooq`:

```
methods of class org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs$JooqVersionAccessors

asProvider(param: org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs.JooqVersionAccessors): org.gradle.api.provider.Provider<kotlin.String!>!
getGradle(param: org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs.JooqVersionAccessors): org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs.JooqGradleVersionAccessors!
equals(param: org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs.JooqVersionAccessors, other: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Boolean
hashCode(param: org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs.JooqVersionAccessors): kotlin.Int
toString(param: org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs.JooqVersionAccessors): kotlin.String
getVersion(param: org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs.JooqVersionAccessors, name: kotlin.String!): org.gradle.api.provider.Provider<kotlin.String!>!
findVersionConstraint(param: org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs.JooqVersionAccessors, name: kotlin.String!): org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ImmutableVersionConstraint!
```

There's an `asProvider()` method there that looks promising, so I tried:

```kotlin
jooq {
        version = libs.versions.jooq.asProvider().get()
```

This works, and I confirmed that it's passing the correct value, but IntelliJ
highlights `asProvider` as an "Unresolved reference".

### tl;dr:

1. Within `build.gradle.kts`, I need to get the version (and only the version) of
   a specific dependency defined in the version catalog so it can be passed as a
   parameter to a task configuration. What is the correct way to do this? (Links
   to official docs would be appreciated.)
2. Is the discrepancy described above a bug in Gradle, IntelliJ, or both?
3. Why does `libs.versions.foo.version` work when the version has a `_version`
   suffix, but things behave completely differently if it does not?

Answer (score 1):

The type of `version` in the Gradle Jooq Plugin extension is `Property<String>` (see [GitHub](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/blob/main/src/main/groovy/nu/studer/gradle/jooq/JooqExtension.java)), and the type of `libs.versions.jooq` from your catalog is `Provider<String>`.

Given that, in Gradle you would set `version`, not by assigning it, but by writing:

```
jooq {
    version.set(libs.versions.jooq)
}
```

Regarding the errors, I don't think I can explain all your problems, but maybe some of the Kotlin code generated from your earlier tries at the TOML catalog remained in the IntelliJ indexes somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with a build.gradle.kts file and have a Compose version defined in a versions.toml file like this:

```ini
[versions]
composeVersion = "1.5.10"
```

To access this version in your build.gradle.kts, you can use the following:

```kotlin
val composeVersion: String by libs.versions
```

However, by doing this, you'll obtain the version in Provider format. If you need to retrieve the raw version string, you can simply call:

```kotlin
val rawComposeVersion: String = libs.versions.composeVersion.get()
```

This will provide you with the plain version string "1.5.10"